# Laravel 5 Exception Handling

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project that will be utilizing a number of custom exception classes. I am realizing that the Handler class is going to get very convoluted with conditional logic in order to check for all of these custom exceptions and trigger the necessary actions. So far, I have not seen many good suggestions online for how best to structure the Handler class or extend the Handler class in a way that will scale for a larger application. Does anyone have some helpful tips?

Comment: Your question is quite wage. Now, I have some ideas that could help you, but I at least need to know what those *"necessary actions"*. Is it just about rendering the correct response or do you want to do more based on the type of exception?

Comment: Depending on the type of exception thrown, I will either be rendering a new view, triggering an email to be sent to the user/admin, creating a record in the logs or some combination of these possible actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there are many ways to go about this.

My idea would be to create an interface for all your exceptions. Something like:

```
interface CustomException {

    /**
     * Handle the exception
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handle();
}
```

Then your exceptions implement that interface and you can use the `handle` method to do all kind of things and return a response in the end.

Your exception handler would then look like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof CustomException) {
        return $e->handle();
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

(Of course you could also separate the interface into `render()` and `report()` like the exception handler is structured itself)

---

Since you need to do some logging and mailing, dependency injection might come in handy:

```
return app()->call([$e, 'handle']);
```

So then you can declare your dependencies:

```
public function handle(\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mail){
   $mail->send(...);
}
```